# Binding a Dependencyproperty as the Datacontext

Tags: c#, dependency-properties, datacontext

I am building a custom control with a Dependencyproperty.  I want the dependencyproperty to be the datacontext of a container in my control.But when I Create a view with my control and I bind the property it doesnt work.
Code example:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyItemsProperty =  
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyItems", typeof (ObservableCollection <object>), typeof (MyControl), 
        new PropertyMetadata (new ObservableCollection <object>()));

    public ObservableCollection <object> MyItems
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection <object> GetValue (MyItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue (MyItemsProperty,  value); }
    }

    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ControlItemHost.DataContext =      MyItems;
    }
}
```

And in the xaml of my control I have a container for the items (ControlItemHost).

When I build the main view and initialize the property:
MyItems="{Binding ListOfItems}"

I dont see the items,  but if I add in MyControl items I see them.
How do I fix this so that I can bind from outside the control?

(It is necessary that the property will be the datacontext)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only assigning a constant value to the DataContext property, instead of establishing a binding. Try the following:

```
ControlItemHost.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty, new Binding("MyItems") { Source = this });
```

Comment: I wrote that in the constructor of MyControl but it still doesn't work when I bind MyItems from a view.

Comment: I added a binding in the views constructor to the property and it worked with your code! I probably have a mistake in the xaml and that's why it didn't work the first time I tried with your answer. Thanks so much!!!!